# Was Final Fantasy I Map part of the game package

Tags: final-fantasy

I'm playing Final Fantasy port for Andorid, I'm using world map from internet to navigate between cities. I'm curious if this was possible to do back in the time of the original game on NES.

Was the World Map part of the instruction manual or game package?

Comment: I do not remember having one, but then again, I bought my copy used from Funcoland

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original NES Final Fantasy came with a [large fold out map of the world](http://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Nintendo_NES/manual/Formated/Final_Fantasy_-_1990_-_Nintendo.pdf).  The other side of the map contained pictures of all the enemies you would encounter in the game, with a little bit of information about each one.

Comment: I'm interested if anybody can link scanned image

Comment: @Hurda -I actually wanted to do that last night, but it appears I got rid of my copy of Final Fantasy.

Comment: I should still have my copy.  I'll see what I can do. ;)